# Matlab:fatal error on Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, matlab

I just download the matlab 2013b and once I start it,
it will automatically close once the main interface have been loaded.

In the workspace of Matlab, i find a log file and is posted below with only the infomation i believe is important.

I have tried to search for some information ,updated my java to the latest version, and re-install the whole matlab, even uninstall the older version
but all seem do nothing on the error, what would be the possible solution?
Thank in advances.

```
    #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000770f004f, pid=9108, tid=5584
#
# JRE version: 7.0_11-b21
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000770f004f
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xc0000005]

# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000064006800):  JavaThread "FileDecorationCache request queue" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5584, stack(0x0000000100000000,0x0000000104000000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000003ffd5d0


> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
> 
> OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1
> 
> CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42
> stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
> sse4.2, popcnt, avx, ht, tsc, tscinvbit
> 
> Memory: 4k page, physical 6127920k(3409508k free), swap
> 12253980k(9240140k free)
> 
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04) for
> windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_11-b21), built on Jan 12 2013 02:38:42 by
> "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600
> 
> time: Wed Apr 23 18:14:36 2014 elapsed time: 83 seconds
```

Comment: Does matlab 2013 support Java 7? AFAIK matlab 2012 doesn't.  I would check which update of Java 7 is supported.  Update 11 is pretty old now.

Comment: Java 7 update 55 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: BTW I suggest asking matlab what you should do, if they don't know, no-one does (or it is not supported)

Comment: FYI, MATLAB is shipped with it's own java.  Here's a support article that may be of use though:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103056-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using

Comment: Your best bet is to contact MathWorks support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found A solution from another site.
The problem can be solved by disable your anti-virus software.
In my case, I am using avast, and once your disable it, there will be no more error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I confirm the origin of the problem. 
I work with Matlab2010a, Windows 10 (64 bits) and Kapersky.
I disabled the antivirus and it works.
Cheers